# How to make __get() called recursively in PHP?

Tags: php

How to let `C::update2()` could access `$this->a` by `__get()`? I'm using PHP 7.

```php
<?php

class C
{
        public $data = [];

        public function __get($p)
        {
                if (!array_key_exists($p, $this->data))
                        $this->fetchData(); // should be a properties to update method mapper
                return $this->data[$p] ?? null;
        }

        public function fetchData()
        {
                $api_data = ['a'=>'123','b'=>'456'];
                $this->data['a'] = $api_data['a'];
                if ($api_data['b'] == '456') {
                        $this->fetch2(); // in this method, it'll call some others API
                } else {
                        $this->fetch3(); // also calls API, but different from update2
                }
        }

        public function fetch2()
        {   
                echo json_encode($this->data)."\n";
                echo $this->a;
        }   

        public function fetch3()
        {   
                echo json_encode($this->data)."\n";
                echo $this->a;
                echo $this->b;
        }   
}

$c = new C;
echo $c->a;
```

output

```
{"a":"123"}
PHP Notice:  Undefined property: C::$a in /test.php on line 27
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /test.php:0
PHP   2. C->__get() /test.php:32
PHP   3. C->fetchData() /test.php:9
PHP   4. C->fetch2() /test.php:18
123
```

The reason I want to do this is I want to make it resolving the properties lazily and without knowing how the properties comes out(black box).

Comment: You could just call the get as in `echo $this->__get('a');`.

Comment: Your update method should only be concerned about building the new property value, not with reading its current value (which is nothing because you cache the result)

Answer (score 0):

After seeing [Nigel Ren's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60239388/how-to-make-get-called-recursively-in-php?noredirect=1#comment106552699_60239388), I gave up on using `$this->prop` syntax in side the class. I use `$this->get('prop')` instead.

```php
public function __get($property)
{
    return $this->get($property);
}

public function get($property)
{
    // resolve the property here
}

// other methods inside class
public function method()
{
    $this->method2($this->get('prop_1') + $this->get('prop_2'));
}
```